# Passing integer to php $_GET via url

Tags: php, type-conversion, ctf

So I'm doing some CTF and one of the challenge is about php type juggling. The code looks something like this

```php
if($_GET['var1'] == hash('md4', $_GET['var1']))
{
//print flag
}
```

So I was 80% sure that I need to pass in an integer so it'll be true but all I can manipulate is the url. I tried using python request to do it but still failed.

```py
import requests
url = 'http://example.com'
params = dict(var1=0)
r = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
```

Is there any special case where php will treat the variable pass into GET array as int? Or there is other way to do so?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but what is a CTF?

Comment: Also unless you have a collision, `$_GET['var1']` cannot be equal to `hash('md4', $_GET['var1'])`.

Comment: I guess https://ctf.hacker101.com/

Comment: @Ibu CTF is Capture The Flag. Also, there is case where it can be. Let's say md4 hash of 0 is ea5698173fc6fdbe30a9af462b9fc847. In php if you compare 0 and a string, if the string doesn't starts with int it'll always return true

Comment: This is a really interesting question. What PHP version are you using?

Comment: @Phil Well, the whole point of this is to find the vulnerabilities. I have no access to the source code so I can't change anything and my job is to exploit this function. If I'm not wrong this exists in every php versions? Type-juggling is always a bug in php

Comment: On my system (PHP 7.2.17), any value in `$_GET` is a string. Only when comparing the actual integer `0` to `ea5698173fc6fdbe30a9af462b9fc847` do I get a _truthy_ result.

Comment: It would work with `True` too, but not a string neither.

Comment: Ah, I understand your question now and I think the answer is no, PHP always treats request parameters as strings

Comment: I'm aware of int and string comparison will result in some false positive result and that's what I want to exploit. But now my question is can I pass in an int to the $_GET array and have it stored as an int instead of string?

Comment: Have you tried not passing anything at all? That should give you null on both sides.

Comment: Again, I think the answer is no. The only other type you can serialize into request parameters is an array by using square brackets, eg `?var1[]=0` but that's unlikely to help

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 nope, the MD4 hash of `null` is `31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0`

Comment: Thanks @Phil. Your answer reminds me of another bug in php with strcmp. If an array is compared to string it'll return 0 haha but in this case it's not going to work XD Guess now I have to research on md4 collisions then. Thanks again

Comment: I am curious about the answer of this problem. Do you think there is any invariant for the md4 function?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this CTF can be found here https://medium.com/@Asm0d3us/part-1-php-tricks-in-web-ctf-challenges-e1981475b3e4

The general idea is to find a value which starts with `0e` and its hash also starts with `0e`. The page gives an example of `0e001233333333333334557778889` which produces a hash of `0e434041524824285414215559233446`

This notation is called scientific notation. To understand why this kind of type juggling works you need to understand what both numbers are. If we convert from scientific notation to decimal it becomes obvious.

`0e001233333333333334557778889` = 0×10<sup>1233333333333334557778889</sup>
`0e434041524824285414215559233446` = 0×10<sup>434041524824285414215559233446</sup>

From primary school maths we know that anything multiplied by 0 is 0, which means both numbers are 0.

All input provided in the `$_GET` or `$_POST` superglobals is of type string. 
Thanks to PHP's type juggling system both strings are treated as floating point numbers written in scientific notation and when cast to float they both equal 0.