# CTF Type Juggling with ripemd160 hash

Tags: php, hash, cryptography, ctf, ripemd

I am trying to solve a CTF in which the juggling type should be used. The code is:

```
if ($_GET["hash"] == hash("ripemd160", $_GET["hash"]))
{
    echo $flag;
}
else
{
    echo "<h1>Bad Hash</h1>";
}
```

I made a script in python which checks random hashes in ripemd160 that begins with "0e" and ends with only numbers. The code is:

```
def id_generator(size, chars=string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
param = "0e"
results = []
while True:
    h = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
    h.update("{0}".format(str(param)).encode('utf-8'))
    hashed = h.hexdigest()
    if param not in results:
        print(param)
        if hashed.startswith("0e") and hashed[2:].isdigit():
            print(param)
            print(hashed)
            break
        results.append(param)
    else:
        print("CHECKED")
    param = "0e" + str(id_generator(size=10))
```

Any suggestions on how to solve it? Thank you!

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what your actual problem is. You are making a bunch of things in Python and testing them in PHP. Is one or the other not working?

Comment: Is a CTF challange. This challenge requires a specific hash parameter sent by GET.  Based on what I was reading about juggling, when comparing two strings starting with "0e" followed by numbers, the comparison is true, no matter if the string is different, it is always true.  The purpose of this CTF is to find the specific string that meets those conditions.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22140266/231316) should point you down a path, hopefully

Comment: It is similar, but in this ctf a verification is performed with the same string, so it must be specific and meet the conditions mentioned above. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Juggling? I have no idea what you mean by juggling. Your php code appears to be looking for a fixed point for the ripemd160 hash. That's not going to happen.

Comment: This link explains about type juggling: https://www.owasp.org/images/6/6b/PHPMagicTricks-TypeJuggling.pdf                                         . And this is an example of the same problem but with md4 hash:      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487143/passing-integer-to-php-get-via-url

Comment: @AgustinRamirez, `==` in PHP is pretty much the same as JS’s double equals, so although they are the same string, because of the `e` they get converted to numbers: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Exactly, but also after "0e" it should only contain numbers. For example, in the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487143/passing-integer-to-php-get-via-url they find the string indicated for the md4 hash, which is "0e001233333333333334557778889". By hashing this string, you get this string "0e434041524824285414215559233446". So, comparing both strings, it would be the same as doing if(0x10^1233... == 0x10^4340...), which is equal to if(0 == 0) and therefore the if is true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bit of misunderstanding in the comments, so I'll start by explaining the problem a little more:

Type juggling refers to the behaviour of PHP whereby variables are implicitly cast to different data types under certain conditions. For example, all the following logical expressions will evaluate to `true` in PHP:

```php
0 == 0                       // int vs. int
"0" == 0                     // str -> int
"abc" == 0                   // any non-numerical string -> 0
"1.234E+03" == "0.1234E+04"  // string that looks like a float -> float
"0e215962017" == 0           // another string that looks like a float
```

The last of these examples is interesting because its MD5 hash value is another string consisting of `0e` followed by a bunch of decimal digits (`0e291242476940776845150308577824`). So here's another logical expression in PHP that will evaluate to `true`:

```php
"0e215962017" == md5("0e215962017")
```

To solve this CTF challenge, you have to find a string that is "equal" to its own hash value, but using the RIPEMD160 algorithm instead of MD5. When this is provided as a query string variable (e.g., `?hash=0e215962017`), then the PHP script will disclose the value of a flag.

Fake hash collisions like this aren't difficult to find. Roughly 1 in every 256 MD5 hashes will start with '0e', and the probability that the remaining 30 characters are all digits is (10/16)^30. If you do the maths, you'll find that the probability of an MD5 hash equating to zero in PHP is approximately one in 340 million. It took me about a minute (almost 216 million attempts) to find the above example.

Exactly the same method can be used to find similar values that work with RIPEMD160. You just need to test more hashes, since the extra hash digits mean that the probability of a "collision" will be approximately one in 14.6 billion. Quite a lot, but still tractable (in fact, I found a solution to this challenge in about 15 minutes, but I'm not posting it here).

Your code, on the other hand, will take much, *much* longer to find a solution. First of all, there is *absolutely no point* in generating random inputs. Sequential values will work just as well, and will be much faster to generate.

If you use sequential input values, then you also won't need to worry about repeating the same hash calculations. Your code uses a list structure to store previously hashed values. This is a *terrible* idea. Searching for an item in a list is an [O(n) operation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), so once your code has (unsuccessfully) tested a billion inputs, it will have to compare every new input against each of these billion inputs at each iteration, causing your code to grind to a complete standstill. Your code would actually run a lot faster if you didn't bother checking for duplicates. When you have time, I suggest you learn [when to use lists, dicts and sets in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3489071/1679849).

Another problem is that your code only tests 10-digit numbers, which means it can only test a maximum of 10 billion possible inputs. Based on the numbers given above, are you sure this is a sensible limit?

Finally, your code is printing every single input string before you calculate its hash. Before your program outputs a solution, you can expect it to print out somewhere in the order of a billion screenfuls of incorrect guesses. Is there any point in doing this? No.

Here's the code I used to find the MD5 collision I mentioned earlier. You can easily adapt it to work with RIPEMD160, and you can convert it to Python if you like (although the PHP code is much simpler):

```php
$n = 0;
while (1) {
    $s = "0e$n";
    $h = md5($s);
    if ($s == $h) break;
    $n++;
}
echo "$s : $h\n";
```

---

**Note:** Use PHP's [hash_equals()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) function and [strict comparison operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/80646/1679849) to avoid this sort of vulnerability in your own code.

Comment: I tried stripping down your Python code to make it run faster, but by the look of things, it could still take hashlib about 1½ hours to find a solution. I'd recommend sticking with PHP in this case.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Very well explained. It took around 5 minutes with PHP. I think I was very wrong about the code and it was simpler than I thought. A greeting!